# SQL: query that creates more than 1 value per ID

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have following table

[image]

I am new to SQL and I want to create a new column that assigns a specific value to an ID based on which conditions are fulfilled. Imagine that when Condition 1 = 'Y' the value 'Value1' is assigned and when both Condition 2 and Condition 3 are equal to 'Y' the value 'Value2' is assigned. So this means that for ID 1, for which all conditions for as well 'Value1' as 'Value2' are fulfilled. So the output should look like this:

[image]

So note that ID = 1 has no two rows, one for each of the values of which the conditions are fulfilled and that for ID = 3 and ID = 4 none of the conditions are fulfilled an so they are assigned null. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `case` is useful for this.  Here is a method that uses `union all`:

```
select id, 'Value1'
from t
where condition1 = 'Y'
union all
select id, 'Value1'
from t
where condition2 = 'Y' and condition3 = 'Y'
union all
select id, NULL
from t
where not (condition1 = 'Y' or (condition2 = 'Y' and condition3 = 'Y'));
```

As written, the code assumes that the conditions are never `NULL`, but that is easily incorporated.